# RichTextBox - check if a linebreak was deleted

Tags: c#, richtextbox, textchanged

I build a little editor with linenumbers. Now I want to delete them if a linebreak is deleted. One way could be that I count the linebreaks on every textchanged event, but I don't like that. Is there a possibility to check if a linebreak was deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store line count in a variable, e.g. `_linesCnt`, then in `TextChanged` event you would compare `_linesCnt` to your richtextbox `Lines.Count` property and if they differ - recount your line numbers.